# Binding an already bound property but with a normalised value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My `ProgressBar` XAML:

```xml
<Window ...>
     <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress}"/>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
internal int Progress { get; set; }
```

This progress variable is in multiples of 1, so values will be 1, 2, 3, so on...

Now I decided to use the same `Progress` property for `TaskBarItemInfo`'s `ProgressValue`. However, I find it accepts a range of only 0.0 to 1.0 (i.e. **normalised** values). Is there a way I can bind the same `Progress` property while specifying some sort of conversion like a division by a number to make it normalised?

Comment: Use a [Binding Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options. You could expose a separate (probably computed) `double` property that is updated each time the `Progress` property is changed, e.g. through raising a `PropertyChanged` (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) event in its setter for the computed property.

Another option is creating a custom value or multi-value converter. If there is a hardcoded or predefined range for your `int` progress values you can create a value converter like this.

```
public class AbsoluteToRelativeProgressConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is int progress) ||
          !(parameter is string maximumText) ||
          !int.TryParse(maximumText, out var maximum))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      if (maximum < progress)
         throw new ArgumentException("Progress must not exceed maximum.");

      return progress / (double)maximum;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

This converter gets the bound progress value passed in as `value`. This value is checked if it is really an `int`. As parameter, you can pass the maximum value. It is passed as `string` to simplify the syntax in XAML (assigning an `int` is verbose). The converter returns the relative progress as `double` in range [0.0, 1.0]. As said before, if the maximum is hardcoded, you could remove the parameter usage and replace the `maximum` with the value.

Next, create an instance of the converter in the `Window.Resources` or any other resource dictionary in scope.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:AbsoluteToRelativeProgressConverter x:Key="AbsoluteToRelativeProgressConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then bind the `Progress` in the `TaskBarItemInfo` to the `ProgressValue` using the converter. The `ConverterParameter` is used to pass the maximum, here `100` as example. Note that you need to set the `ProgressState` to e.g. `Normal`, `Error` or `Paused`, otherwise the progress bar will not be shown.

```
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
   <TaskbarItemInfo ProgressState="Normal"
                    ProgressValue="{Binding Progress, Converter={StaticResource AbsoluteToRelativeProgressConverter}, ConverterParameter=100}"/>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter x:Key="AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

If you want to bind the maximum value, too, you need to create a [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) like this.

```
public class AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values is null ||
          values.Length != 2 ||
          !(values[0] is int progress) ||
          !(values[1] is int maximum))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      if (maximum < progress)
         throw new ArgumentException("Progress must not exceed maximum.");

      return progress / (double)maximum;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

It works the same but allows for binding multiple values. Here, the progress is the first value for the converter and the maximum is the second. You could easily extend this converter, to bind a minium value, too.

In XAML, you create an instance, too, but this time you use a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter x:Key="AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
   <TaskbarItemInfo ProgressState="Normal">
      <TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AbsoluteToRelativeProgressMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Progress"/>
            <Binding Path="Maximum"/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue>
   </TaskbarItemInfo>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

As a note, if you wanted to make the `ProgressState` depend on the `Progress` property, like setting `Normal` if the progress is `>= 0` and `<= maximum`, guess what, you could use create a converter...or a separate property of course.

Answer (score 0):

xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <local:DataConverter  x:Key="dataConverter " />
</Window.Resources>


 <ProgressBar Value={Binding Path=Progress, Converter={StaticResource dataConverter }}/>
```

converter code

```
public class DataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       // read the input from value and cast it
       // return your object;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```